# Drag and Drop a view/element into options of target view in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

I have a view/element i want to drag and drop that into a options of target element in react native, Can anyone help how to proceed or which library is suitable for that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain your use-case a bit more? Maybe a graphical visualization of what you want to achieve? Or links to an example page that has this feature.

Comment: I have a component , i target areas, let us assume 10 components namely 1 2 3 4 to 10 , I have a compnent i want to drag and drop this component to one of the 10 target component. and save the component in target area state.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable

Comment: @MortenHekkvang , The usecase is that I have a text and 10 boxes and i want to drag that text to one of these boxes, and save the text to the box state,  What is the approach, which library to use , I am all new to it